# Which Adapter to use?

Tags: android, android-adapter

REQUIREMENT:
I am working on GRE vocab app. I have requirement in which I will be showing word at the header level and four meaning in the lower section and out four meanings one will be the correct one.

I will be using TextView control to show these words and meanings.

QUESTION:
I want to implement adapter? I don't know which one suits? which Adapter? my requirement is basically show line and header details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure a `ListView` and `Adapter` make sense for you.

Why not add your four options to a `LinearLayout` and keep it simple?

Much of the adapter infrastructure is dedicated to recycling views, avoiding pre-loading a large number of rows, and dealing with multiple types of rows. If you don't need any of this, then a `LinearLayout` might make sense.

Comment: I am doing it in LinerLayout . Please forgive my ignorance, so you are saying , if I am using LinerLayout then i dont need to implements adapters and all that.

Comment: Don't forget about adding a `ScrollView` around the `LinearLayout` to help users with smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) with either a String[] or List of the definitions.

Comment: What do think Roddy ? I should go with Mattew suggestion

Comment: I would go with Matthew's suggestion if you are not looking to expand your choices past just a couple on one page.